# How to extract certain outputs from a non-S4 object?

Tags: r

```
require(datasets)
require(splines)
obj <- bs(women$height, df = 5)
obj
                 1           2           3            4           5
 [1,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [2,] 4.534439e-01 0.059857872 0.001639942 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [3,] 5.969388e-01 0.203352770 0.013119534 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [4,] 5.338010e-01 0.376366618 0.044278426 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [5,] 3.673469e-01 0.524781341 0.104956268 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [6,] 2.001640e-01 0.595025510 0.204719388 9.110787e-05 0.000000000
 [7,] 9.110787e-02 0.566326531 0.336734694 5.830904e-03 0.000000000
 [8,] 3.125000e-02 0.468750000 0.468750000 3.125000e-02 0.000000000
 [9,] 5.830904e-03 0.336734694 0.566326531 9.110787e-02 0.000000000
[10,] 9.110787e-05 0.204719388 0.595025510 2.001640e-01 0.000000000
[11,] 0.000000e+00 0.104956268 0.524781341 3.673469e-01 0.002915452
[12,] 0.000000e+00 0.044278426 0.376366618 5.338010e-01 0.045553936
[13,] 0.000000e+00 0.013119534 0.203352770 5.969388e-01 0.186588921
[14,] 0.000000e+00 0.001639942 0.059857872 4.534439e-01 0.485058309
[15,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000e+00 1.000000000
attr(,"degree")
[1] 3
attr(,"knots")
33.33333% 66.66667% 
 62.66667  67.33333 
attr(,"Boundary.knots")
[1] 58 72
attr(,"intercept")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"class")
[1] "bs"     "basis"  "matrix"
```

I want to extract the 15 x 5 matrix of values from `obj`, which is a `bs` object. I've tried using the `@` operator but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a `matrix` with some attributes

```
attributes(obj)$class
```

So the 'obj' should have all the properties of the `matrix` with some extra.  An easy way to get rid of the attributes, is just convert to `data.frame` and then to matrix again

```
 as.matrix(as.data.frame(obj))
                 1           2           3            4           5
 [1,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [2,] 4.534439e-01 0.059857872 0.001639942 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [3,] 5.969388e-01 0.203352770 0.013119534 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [4,] 5.338010e-01 0.376366618 0.044278426 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [5,] 3.673469e-01 0.524781341 0.104956268 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [6,] 2.001640e-01 0.595025510 0.204719388 9.110787e-05 0.000000000
 [7,] 9.110787e-02 0.566326531 0.336734694 5.830904e-03 0.000000000
 [8,] 3.125000e-02 0.468750000 0.468750000 3.125000e-02 0.000000000
 [9,] 5.830904e-03 0.336734694 0.566326531 9.110787e-02 0.000000000
[10,] 9.110787e-05 0.204719388 0.595025510 2.001640e-01 0.000000000
[11,] 0.000000e+00 0.104956268 0.524781341 3.673469e-01 0.002915452
[12,] 0.000000e+00 0.044278426 0.376366618 5.338010e-01 0.045553936
[13,] 0.000000e+00 0.013119534 0.203352770 5.969388e-01 0.186588921
[14,] 0.000000e+00 0.001639942 0.059857872 4.534439e-01 0.485058309
[15,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000e+00 1.000000000
```

---

Or another option is to assign those additional attributes to NULL.  If this is done on the same object, we will lose those attributes

```
attributes(obj)[setdiff(names(attributes(obj)), c("dim", "dimnames"))] <- NULL
> obj
                 1           2           3            4           5
 [1,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [2,] 4.534439e-01 0.059857872 0.001639942 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [3,] 5.969388e-01 0.203352770 0.013119534 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [4,] 5.338010e-01 0.376366618 0.044278426 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [5,] 3.673469e-01 0.524781341 0.104956268 0.000000e+00 0.000000000
 [6,] 2.001640e-01 0.595025510 0.204719388 9.110787e-05 0.000000000
 [7,] 9.110787e-02 0.566326531 0.336734694 5.830904e-03 0.000000000
 [8,] 3.125000e-02 0.468750000 0.468750000 3.125000e-02 0.000000000
 [9,] 5.830904e-03 0.336734694 0.566326531 9.110787e-02 0.000000000
[10,] 9.110787e-05 0.204719388 0.595025510 2.001640e-01 0.000000000
[11,] 0.000000e+00 0.104956268 0.524781341 3.673469e-01 0.002915452
[12,] 0.000000e+00 0.044278426 0.376366618 5.338010e-01 0.045553936
[13,] 0.000000e+00 0.013119534 0.203352770 5.969388e-01 0.186588921
[14,] 0.000000e+00 0.001639942 0.059857872 4.534439e-01 0.485058309
[15,] 0.000000e+00 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000e+00 1.000000000
> str(obj)
 num [1:15, 1:5] 0 0.453 0.597 0.534 0.367 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```